# Show that $x-x^2=\frac{1}{3}$ has no real solutions.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

I have graphed this equation, which shows that there are no real solutions to this equation. How would I go about showing this without relying on a graph?

Comment: If the radicand of the quadratic formula is negative, i.e; $b^2-4ac<0$, then it should not have real solutions.

Comment: How about by looking at the functions y=x(x-1) and y=-1/3 and showing the region for which this function is negative and the range of it in that demain? Or by using quadratic formula and showing you would have the squareroot of a negative number?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  If you know calculus, then you know that $x-x^2$ is maximized when $x=\frac12$, but since this is tagged [tag:algebra-precalculus] I gave an answer without invoking derivatives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert it to the form $ax^2 +bx+c=0$. If $b^2 -4ac<0,$ then there are no real solutions. This is trivial when looking at the quadratic formula.

Answer (score 4):

$$x^2-x+\frac13\gt x^2-x+\frac14=\left(x-\frac12\right)^2\ge0$$

Comment: $x^2-x-\frac{1}{3}$?

Comment: @mjw:  I don't think so.  $x-x^2=\dfrac13\iff x^2-x\color{red}+\dfrac13=0$

Comment: Oh, I read that (the title) too quickly

Answer (score 0):

I mean the easiest way is to use the [discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant) (as mentioned in the first comment). But hey, why use the quadratic equation when you can just complete the square (i.e. derive the quadratic equation):

$$
x^2 - x  +\frac{1}{3} = 0\\
\left(x - \frac{1}{2}\right)^2 + \frac{1}{3} + ? = 0 \\
x^2 - x + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{3} + ? = 0 \leadsto ? = -\frac{1}{4}\\
\left(x - \frac{1}{2}\right)^2 + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{4} = 0 \\
\left(x - \frac{1}{2}\right)^2 + \frac{1}{12}= 0 \\
\left(x - \frac{1}{2}\right)^2 = -\frac{1}{12}
$$

A real value cannot be squared (positive or negative) to give a negative result, so this has no real solutions.

If we inspect $b^2 - 4ac$, we find:

$$
1 - \frac{4}{3} = -\frac{1}{3} < 0 \leadsto\ \text{no real solutions}
$$

...no surprise, if we do a little manipulation, we can see this value in our above equation:

$$
\left(2\left(x - \frac{1}{2}\right)\right)^2 = (2x - 1)^2 = 4\left(x - \frac{1}{2}\right)^2
$$

So we can use that and just multiply each side by 4

$$
(2x - 1)^2 = -\frac{1}{3}
$$